# Why doesn't compiler accept arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

This is the easiest of arrays and I can't even get this to work! Is there something missing in my code? Or is there something wrong with my compiler?

Code:

```
public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] aryNums = new int[6];
        aryNums[0] = 10;
        aryNums[1] = 20;
        aryNums[2] = 30;
        aryNums[3] = 40;
        aryNums[4] = 50;
        aryNums[5] = 60;
        aryNums[6] = 70;
        System.out.println(aryNums[2]);
    }
}
```

After running this code I get the message below from the compiler:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at example.main(example.java:12)
```

I run jre7 and my compiler/program that I use is eclipse lunar SR2 (4.4.2). I used to be really into Java a while back but I just got back into Java so I don't know if my code is right or not.

Thanks

Comment: Hint. --> You are creating an array of size 6.. and add "how" many elements?

Comment: This is the most fundamental of array errors. `int[6]` means indices 0 to 5.

Comment: Im an idiot |facepalm|

Comment: No you aren't. Trivial errors happen, even the most nimble programmers (that's not me ...) suffer from them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count it, you adress 7 parts of the array, but your array is defined with the size 6, reaching from index 0-5. This causes the assigning from `aryNums[6]` to throw an error, since it´s above the maximum elements of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has a size of 6 (0 to 5) and you're trying to fill a sixth case that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your array needs to have 7 elements, not 6. Note that you reported a *runtime* error on a (no offense intended) toy example - this combination in general makes a compiler error highly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has 6 positions, as it starts in 0 that gives you from 0 to 5. 6 is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You size the array to 6 and try to add 7 elements.